# Омонимы: есть (является, имеется) и есть (кушать)

Tags: омонимы

Интересно, а случайно ли одинаковое звучание слов "есть" (является, имеется) и "есть" (кушать)?

Answer (score 1):

Не понял. А какое значение тут "одинаковое"? Здесь одинаковое звучание (омонимия), но *разные* значения.

Простите, я не знаю, Вы ли автор вопроса в подобной формулировке (он изменен другим пользователем), поэтому прошу не обижаться за нижеследующее предположение.

Если Вы спрашиваете про омонимичность слов "есть" (является, имеется) и "есть" (кушать), то она действительно случайна. Эти слова восходят к разным индоевропейским корням, более того "есть-кушать" до недавнего времени писалось через ять, что уже само по себе исключает всякое родство.

Comment: Я исправил только опечатку в заглавии ( были обонимы вместо омонимы), не вчитываясь в вопрос. Сейчас подправил и *значение-звучание*. У вас, кстати, тоже есть такая возможность.

Comment: Марк Из, можно я просто промолчу?

Comment: Я думаю, тут действительно опечатка, и автор имел в виду, естественно, одинаковое звучание. И уверена, что behemothus (который сам делает множество опечаток, надо сказать) прекрасно это понял. Просто, ну никак же не мог упустить случая унизить спрашивающего.

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki, воля Ваша модераторская, но я никаким боком не хотел задеть **спрашивающего**. Да и не вижу в своем тексте такого.
Если Вам непонятно, я дейстивительно счел, что исправивший по своему обыкновению запутался в формулировке. 
Что до моих опечаток, так я их и не отрицаю. Но это опечатки.  
И еще. Я никогда не беру на себя смелость решать за другого, что он **хотел сказать**, считаю это крайне неприличным.

Спасибо за понимание. 
Надеюсь эти претензии не превратятся в тенденцию, как это уже имело место.

Comment: Спасибо за понимание. 
Надеюсь эти претензии не превратятся в тенденцию, как это уже имело место.

Comment: behemothus! Когда нажимаешь на слова "Изменен ..." открывается вся история изменений. И первоначальный вариант виден.

Comment: @behemothus, помнится вы и сами обиделись, когда я в своём комментарии к вашему ответу написал значение слова "компост".

 Amano, далеко не новичок на этом форуме и то, как пишется слово "омоним" и чем отличается "звучание", от "значение" наверняка знает. Утверждение, что человек, с рейтингом 608 и 28 медалями не знает, чем отличается "значение" и "звучание", действительно оскорбительно.

У новичка эти опечатки, я исправлять бы не стал.

Comment: >behemothus! Когда нажимаешь на слова "Изменен ..." открывается вся история изменений. И первоначальный вариант виден.  
  
О как! Спасибо огромное. Тогда снимается.
А год назад я что-то такого не видел. Ну бывает и на старуху поруха.
Приношу всем извинения.

Хотя вопрос о правомерности **авторизованной** замены "значение" на "звучание" для меня по-прежнему открыт. 

>@behemothus, помнится вы и сами обиделись, 
  
Я на ВАС нен обижаюсь. Просто считаю недостойным решать за другого, что и как он сделал. Особенно, если это никак не следует из его текста.

Comment: Да все нормально. Но я действительно хотел узнать, одно ли происхождение у этих слов, или это просто случайное созвучие.  
Большое спасибо всем ответившим и прокомментировавшим.